# Failure installing Go dependency

Tags: go

I have installed Go on my server using the golang repo for CentOS 6.4. The paths are set correctly and I can run go version. When I try to download the package below I receive this error. Any help is appreciated

```
go get github.com/fiorix/freegeoip
# github.com/fiorix/freegeoip
cannot create <nil>/go.o: No such file or directory
```

Comment: you probably don't have $GOPATH set correctly. can you paste the output of `go env` please? Also, can you `go get` other packages?

Comment: here is the output of go env
go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/www/geocode"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib64/golang"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib64/golang/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"

Comment: Clone the repo yourself and see if this problem is git related.

Comment: does `/home/www/geocode` exist? does the user who does the `go get` have access to it? I just installed it here and it works fine.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer the folder does exist and the www user owns it. it also writes the pkg and src folders with data before it fails.

Comment: from a bit of reading, it sounds like a missing TMPDIR in your env. try something like `export TMPDIR=/tmp` and see if it helps.

Comment: I'll post it as a reply for future generations :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

googling that error I came across a thread that suggests that this is a bug with detecting a missing `TMPDIR` environment variable, for compiling the source during `go get`.

run `export TMPDIR=/tmp` and it should work.

See here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-dev/LnxmgwB0r3Q